# No carga CSS en un archivo de ruta Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

estoy haciendo un servidor en Nodejs con ejs. Estoy intentado crear archivos independientes para las rutas. Hasta ahora he creado dos. Uno de ellos funciona perfectamente, pero las rutas que tengo en el otro archivo no carga los archivos CSS. ¿Tienen idea de que puede ser?

GuestController (El que funciona)

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const path = require('path');


router.get('/' , (req , res)=>{

res.render('pages-body/home');

 });



module.exports = router
```

LoginController(el que no carga los estilos)

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const path = require('path');


router.get('/sign-up' , (req , res)=>{

res.render('pages-body/register');

});


module.exports = router
```

index.js

```
...
//Use static route for resources
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/resources')));

//Controllers
const GuestController = require(path.join(__dirname, '/app/controllers/GuestController'));
const LoginController = require(path.join(__dirname, '/app/controllers/auth/LoginController'));

app.use('/', GuestController)
app.use('/auth', LoginController)

//Set View Engine and Layout
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
```

head.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css" />
<title>Arcana by HTML5 UP</title>
</head>
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Deberías agregar y revisar el fragmento de código de ejs donde cargas los estilos, probablemente ahí esté el error.

Comment: El fragmento de codigo es **<%- include('../partials/head'); %>** y esta en los dos archivos. Pero en uno funciona y en otro no

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir el contenido de /partials/head?

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Pues la verdad no parece haber problema. ¿Inspeccionaste con chrome developer tools en la página que no se muestra el css a ver si el header se está importando correctamente? Es decir, ¿te muestra el header?

Comment: si aparece, te dejo enlace: https://ibb.co/4tPCmj8

Comment: Vale, he encontrado el fallo: como el archivo de rutas tiene el middleware /auth, no se por que, el href de los estilos los ubica en /auth/assets/css/main.css, cuando deberia ubicarlos en /assets/css/main.css ¿Sabes como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Vale, he encontrado el fallo: como el archivo de rutas tiene el middleware /auth, no se por que, el href de los estilos los ubica en /auth/assets/css/main.css, cuando deberia ubicarlos en assets/css/main.css. La solucion era simplemente poner / delante de assets, de manera que quedaria así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css" />
```

Comment: Me alegra hayas solucionado el problema.